# what is this console message from vMenu

Tags: c#, fivem

I got an error in my console coming from [vMenu](https://docs.vespura.com/vmenu/home/)?
Does anyone know what it is?

> Error invoking callback for event playerConnecting: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: int CitizenFX.Core.Native.API.StartFindKvp(string)
> at vMenuServer.BanManager.CheckForBans (CitizenFX.Core.Player source, System.String playerName, CitizenFX.Core.CallbackDelegate kickCallback) [0x0000d] in :0
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in :0
> Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00083] in :0
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x000e7] in :0
> at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00008] in :0
> at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0
> at CitizenFX.Core.EventHandlerEntry.Invoke (System.String sourceString, System.Object[] args) [0x00064] in C:\gl\builds\4ff63adb\0\cfx\fivem\code\client\clrcore\EventHandlerDictionary.cs:89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `vMenu` is using reflection to invoke a certain function.

Reflection can throw runtime exception like this for two reasons.

- There is no assembly referenced that contains said function
- The assembly is there but the version is wrong and does not contain the function needed or that specific overload.

You should try with another version and re-install (better try another version)

Otherwise start a bug on the author's github to get suggestions and/or a fix.